# Swift's Checking Type

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

[Here is swift tutorial link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_511)!

Example is:

```
  let library = [
       Movie(name: "Casablanca", director: "Michael Curtiz"),
       Song(name: "Blue Suede Shoes", artist: "Elvis Presley"),
       Movie(name: "Citizen Kane", director: "Orson Welles"),
       Song(name: "The One And Only", artist: "Chesney Hawkes"),
       Song(name: "Never Gonna Give You Up", artist: "Rick Astley")
  ]
```

tutorial say:
If you iterate over the contents of this array, the items you receive back are typed as MediaItem, and not as Movie or Song.

And Checking Type say:
Use the type check operator (is) to check whether an instance is of a certain subclass type. The type check operator returns true if the instance is of that subclass type and false if it is not.

```
var movieCount = 0
var songCount = 0

for item in library {
  if item is Movie {
    ++movieCount
  } else if item is Song {
    ++songCount
  }
}
```

So when i get item , item's type is MediaItem

but why "item is Movie" will return trun??

Because Movie is subclass of MediaItem

So If i get MediaItem type

It should be written as　"Movie is item "

Mean Movie is subclass of MediaItem right?

but why is written "item is Movie"

Comment: You are aware that `Movie` and `Song` are subclasses of `MediaItem`? Or do you have trouble understanding the concept of inheritance?

Comment: Are you understanding  my problem?

Comment: My problem is why "item is Movie" is true,
because item is MediaItem type not Movie type

Comment: Of course it's true, that's Inheritance 101. Which is why I asked you whether you have trouble understanding the concept of inheritance.

Comment: I know Movie Inheritance from MediaItem ,
but MediaItem type is not Movie type right?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have trouble with the difference between the type of a *variable* and the type of the *object* that is assigned to the variable.

Maybe this might give you a little insight:

```
let movie = Movie(name: "Casablanca", director: "Michael Curtiz")
var test : AnyObject = movie

println(test is Movie) // "true" since it's an instance of Movie
println(test is MediaItem) // "true" since Movie is a subclass of MediaItem
println(test is Song) // "false", it's not a Song.

// Assign to variable of type MediaItem works because Movie is
// a subclass of MediaItem
let item : MediaItem = movie

println(item is Movie) // "true" since the object really is a Movie
println((item as AnyObject) is MediaItem) // "true" since Movie is a subclass of MediaItem
println(item is Song) // "false", it's not a Song.

// The next line does NOT work: "upcasting" is not allowed.
// You will get a compiler error here.
let anotherMovie : Movie = item
```

Comment: @CKvir: Swift's compiler is too smart here and raises an error when it detects that a condition will always be true… but if you like code that work, see my update. My example was trying to show you an important point of inheritance; I didn't expect you to compile it, reading it should be enough.

Comment: The correct version that compiles does not show the point I was trying to make as clearly. The main thing you need to understand is that the type of an _object_ can be different from the type of the _variable_ it is assigned to: even though `item` is of type `MediaItem`, the object it points to is actually a `Movie`. Likewise, `test` is of type `AnyObject` but the object it points to is also `Movie` (in fact, both `test` and `item` point to the very same object).